# Loop an UIElement variable name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, loops, variables

I try to loop the names of my food objects in an WPF application.

I want the following names of the foodelement: food0, food1, foot2 ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < foods.Count; i++)
{
    System.Windows.UIElement foodelement = "food" + i; // ERROR here
    Canvas.SetLeft(foodelement, foods[i].Position.X);
}
```

I get the error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Windows.UIElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
System.Windows.UIElement foodelement = (System.Windows.UIElement)YourContainer.FindName("food" + i);
```

Where `YourContainer` is the the container(grid/canvas/stack panel/) that holds the UIElements.

Or else you can use the following:

```
 System.Windows.UIElement foodelement = UIHelper.FindChild<System.Windows.UIElement>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "food" + i);
```

Comment: myCanvas does not contain .FindControl()

Comment: Thank you un-lucky. But what is the base class of UIHelper? I could not found it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Following code will help you

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree. 
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
> /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
> /// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
> /// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
> /// If not matching item can be found, 
> /// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
> public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
>    where T : DependencyObject
> {
>     // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
>     if (parent == null) return null;
>
>     T foundChild = null;
>
>     int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
>     for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
>     {
>         var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
>         // If the child is not of the request child type child
>         T childType = child as T;
>         if (childType == null)
>         {
>             // recursively drill down the tree
>             foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
>
>             // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
>             if (foundChild != null) break;
>         }
>         else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
>         {
>             var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
>             // If the child's name is set for search
>             if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
>             {
>                 // if the child's name is of the request name
>                 foundChild = (T)child;
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             // child element found.
>             foundChild = (T)child;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return foundChild;
> }
> ```

And use this method

> ```
>   for (int i = 0; i < foods.Count; i++)
>        {
>         System.Windows.UIElement ui = FindChild<Button>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "food" + i);
>        }
> ```